# Relation many-to-many with attribut

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got trouble with symfony 2 and relations.

I've got 2 tables: **cinema** and **film**.
I'd like to add a relation between them using a middle object which contain more informations about the link (such as the cinema URL for instance).

Unfortunatly when I try to save my form I get this following errors:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 
>         `'MyNameSapce\CoreBundle\Entity\Movie#cinemas'`
>    that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 
>   `MyNameSapce\CoreBundle\Entity\MovieCinema@0000000059c00fdd00000000cd3391df`.
>
> Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship.
>
> If you    cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   `'MyNameSapce\CoreBundle\Entity\MovieCinema#__toString()'` to get a clue.

Here is my code:
**Entity:**

```php
class MovieCinema {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyNameSpace\CoreBundle\Entity\Cinema", inversedBy="movies")
 */
private $cinema;

 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyNameSpace\CoreBundle\Entity\Movie", inversedBy="cinemas")
 */
private $movie;

   /**
 * @var string $url
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="integer")
 */
private $url;
```

**Forms:**

```php
class MovieCinemaType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('cinema', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'movie.field.cinema',
                'class' => 'MyNameSpaceCoreBundle\Entity\Cinema',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('url', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'movie.field.url'
            ))
    ;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'corebundle_moviecinematype';
}


public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
            'data_class' => 'MyNameSpace\CoreBundle\Entity\MovieCinema'
            );
}

}
```

and

```php
class MovieType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'movie.field.name'
            ))
            ->add('cinemas', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new MovieCinemaType,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true)
            )
    ;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'corebundle_movietype';
}

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of `MyNameSpace\CoreBundle\Entity\Cinema`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your mapping by doing that: `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`

It will help you to find errors in your relations between your 3 classes.